# IBM mobile first, is it possible to segregate logs of multiple java adapters in different files?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have more than 15 java adapters which are used in multiple application. I want to segregate logs in different files. is it possible in IBM MFP v8?

Comment: System out logging? Or you're using a logging framework? If not, can you?

Comment: Yes, I am using logger from java.util.logging @dbreaux

Comment: So each adapter can use its own logging configuration file, can't it? Thus logging to different destinations.